# Bootstrap confidence interval - c++

Tags: c#, c++, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I know how to calculate CI in R and Matlab, but for a new webapp I'd like to use some c++ code or c#, for and easier implementation.

A really simple method could be to use as confidence interval bounds, the 5th and 95th quantiles.
An example of code for quantile calculation is the follow:
http://cplusplus.happycodings.com/Beginners_Lab_Assignments/code52.html

My question is: do you have some code in c++ or c# for computation of CI with BCa?

Comment: Usually a 95% CI is reported, which requires the 2.5 and 97.5 percentiles. You can compute this quite easily in C++: (1) `std::sort` and (2) get the right percentile.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marc, I've done as you said.